# IDE doesn't recognize method using JSDoc

Tags: javascript, function, webstorm, jsdoc

I've got a function defined like the one below.

```
/**
 * @type Object
 * @return {typeof hello} hello
 */

function hello() {

    /**
     * Prints some words
     * @param {string} words - words to print
     * @returns {string} words you said
     */
    function sayIt(words) {
        console.log(words);
        return 'You said: ' + words;
    }
    return {
        sayIt: sayIt
    }
}
```

I would like it so that when I type `hello.` my IDE would tell me that the method `sayIt` is available and that it takes in the parameter `words` as a string.

This function is getting loaded as a module into a cloud system and the only way you can call it from another script is by importing the `hello` module and using it like `hello.sayIt('hello')`. So basically I'm wondering if there is a way to format the JSDoc so that my IDE knows that the `sayIt` method is available to the `hello` object and that it takes in a `words` parameter as a string. At present it knows that `sayIt` is a method but does not know that it is associated with the `hello` object, so I don't get any auto completion help.

Comment: So, you keep saying "IDE", but what you really mean is WebStorm, judging from the tag. There's documentation on how to add JSDoc properly in the help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/creating-jsdoc-comments.html

Answer (score 0):

Webstorm should be able to give you autocorrect even if you don't have JSDOC for your code.

Check that you have  `module.exports = hello` and not `module.exports = hello()`

If this suggestion does not work or does not apply, I would advise refactoring your code

I would recommend you do this instead.

```
return {
  sayIt: function(words) {
    console.log(words);
    return 'You said: ' + words;
  }
}
```